# How do I find all $z\in \Bbb{C}$ such that the following series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I have the following series:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(2z-1)^n
$$
and I need to find all $z\in \Bbb{C}$ such that the series converge. My Idea was the following, let us remark that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(2z-1)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\left(2\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^n n\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n.
$$
Now I define $a_n=2^nn$ and I want to compute the radius of convergence. To do so we need
$$
\lim sup_{n\rightarrow \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}.
$$
Let us remark that
$$
|2^nn|^{1/n}=2|n^{1/n}|\rightarrow 2\cdot 1=2;
$$
thus, since the limit exists we know that $\lim sup_{n\rightarrow \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}=\lim |a_n|^{1/n}=2$, therefore the radius of convergence is
$$
r=1/2
$$
and the series converges on $\{z:|z-1/2|<r\}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: so is my result wrong or does it work like this because we don't have seen the ratio test yet?

Comment: I don't understand what Doge is trying to say. Seems correct to me, as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to do any transformation. The radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n z^n$ is just $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$$

Therefore, when $|2z-1|<1$, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(2z-1)^n$ converge. And if $|2z-1|\ge 1$, the term $ |n(2z-1)^n|\rightarrow\infty\not=0$, so the series diverge.

Comment: ah wow, this makes sense, but sorry is my solution wrong? so I mean I see it is overcomplicated but if we forget about this would it also work.

Comment: It works, except the radius of convergence doesn't tell whether the series converge on the circle $|z-1/2|=r$ at all.

Comment: Sorry I had an idea for my question befor, can't I say that I onla need to check the situation $z-1/2=\pm 1/2$ then I plug this into my series and I see that $n(2\cdot (\pm 1/2)^n=n(\pm 1)^n$ does not converge to zero and thus the serie does not converge either would this work?

Comment: Yeah, that works. (There were typos in my last now deleted comment).

Comment: perfect thanks. Yes I thought they where typos.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, I would start with noticing that

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(2z - 1)^{n} & = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(2z - 1)^{n}\\
& = (2z - 1)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(2z - 1)^{n-1}\\
& = (2z - 1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(2z - 1)^{n}
\end{align*}

Moreover, we also have the geometric series:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1 - w} = 1 + w + w^{2} + \ldots = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}w^{n}
\end{align*}
which converges whenever $|w| < 1$. Due to its properties, we can derive both sides in order to get:
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{1}{1 - w}\right)^{2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nw^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n + 1)w^{n}
\end{align*}

Comparing both results, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(2z - 1)^{n} & = (2z - 1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n + 1)(2z - 1)^{n}  = \frac{2z - 1}{4(1 - z)^{2}}
\end{align*}

which converges whenever $|2z - 1| < 1$, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps !

**EDIT**

According to the root test, the proposed series converges when
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_{n}(2z - 1)^{n}|^{1/n} & = \limsup_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}|2z - 1| = |2z - 1| < 1
\end{align*}

Comment: And what if I didn't seen this? So would my approach doesn't work? I ask because your work is nice but I would never come up with this idea at the moment.

Comment: @Wave Then I advise you to apply the ratio or root test. Unfortunately, you overcomplicated things. I am going to edit my answer in order to include the root test.

Comment: okey perfect this would be nice if you include the root thest

Comment: sorry but we have another root test

Comment: So I mean we have the following theorem named root test: if $\sum a_n(z-z_0)^n$ is a power series define $R=\frac{1}{\lim sup_{n\rightarrow \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}}$ then the series converges absolutly in $|z-z_0|<R$ converges uniformly in $|z-z_0|\leq r$ where $r<R$ and diverges if $|z-z_0|>R$

Comment: So how would I do it then using my statement

Comment: @Wave, your first post is correct the way you wrote it, no need for further modification. Atila's answer just shows that the function has only one pole at $z = 1$, so the radius of convergence (centered at $1/2$) is the distance from $1/2$ to $1$, that is, $r = 1/2$.